# Linq perform join with updated field

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 classes A and B, in which I wish to perform a linq query returning the class A (with all its members) along with a field from B.

Here is the class in which I'm returning:

```
public partial class A
{
    // fields in A
    public int classID { get; set; }
    public string mem_1A { get; set; }
    public string mem_2A { get; set; }
    public int points { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Here is the class in which I'm joining against:

```
public partial class B
{
    // fields in B
    public int classID { get; set; }
    public string mem_1B { get; set; }
    public string mem_2B { get; set; }
    public int points { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I've attempted the following variations but I wasn't able to get it working.

```
var db = new MyDBContext();

IEnumerable<A> result1 = 
    from tblA in db.A
    join tblB in db.B on tblA.classID equals tblB.classID 
    select tblA;

IEnumerable<A> result2 = db.A.Join(db.B, x => x.classID, y => y.classID,(x,y) => x);
```

I'm only get all the members in A, but my `points` variable in `class A` is empty. I know I need to perform an assignment from the points in B, but I don't know how to do. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this:

```
var result1 = 
    from tblA in db.A
    join tblB in db.B on tblA.classID equals tblB.classID 
    select new { ClassA = tblA, PointsOfB = tblB.points };
```

It will create an anonymous class that holds tblA and the points of tblB.

---

Update the current value:

```
var result1 = 
    (from tblA in db.A
    join tblB in db.B on tblA.classID equals tblB.classID 
    select new { ClassA = tblA, PointsOfB = tblB.points }).ToArray(); // <-- note this....

foreach(var r in result1)
    r.ClassA.points = r.PointsOfB;

IEnumerable<A> classAUpdated = result1.Select(a => a.ClassA);
```

---

Or in one line:

```
IEnumerable<A> classAList = db.A
    .Join(db.B, a => a.classID, b => b.classID,(a,b) => new 
        { 
            ClassA = a, 
            PointsOfB = b.points 
        }).ToArray ()   // <---------- to persist it
    .Select(ab => 
        { 
            ab.ClassA.points = ab.PointsOfB; 
            return ab.ClassA; 
        });
```

But you should test it.

Comment: Is there a way to create class `A` instead of the anonymous class?

Comment: Then you need to assign the values or recreate the class. I'll give an example. The problem is, you're not able to update the rows. Do you need the row to be updatable in the database?

Comment: The one line almost worked. It throws an error when the point assignment occurs:  `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree. An expression tree may not contain assignment operator`

Comment: This is because it want to convert it to an expression (iqueryable)  ill update it.

Comment: If you want to add conditions (where statement) u should add it **before** the `ToArray ()`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is what you want

```
 var result2 = db.A.Join(db.B, x => x.classID, y => y.classID,(x,y) =>
                 new{classA = x,
                 pontOfB = y.points });
```

if you want it in classA, try this

```
 var result2 = db.A.Join(db.B, x => x.classID, y => y.classID,(x,y) =>
                 new classA {
                 classId  = x.classId,
                 mem_1a = x.mem_1a,
                 mem_1b = x.mem_1b,                   
                 points = y.points });
```

Comment: Is there a way to create class `A` instead of the anonymous class?

Comment: where will you store your points from b in that case ... another approach will be to create a new class with classA and points as its member

Comment: the points from `B` would be stored in `A`. So `A.points = B.points`.